# How to make a variable choose a specified link

Tags: php, variables

I am working on a PHP IPN script for PayPal. When an item is added to the cart it is given an `item_name`. Each `item_name` has a corresponding link that goes with it.

Example:

```
<?php
  $digital_product_path=
  ["Item1book", "http://somewebsite.com/item1.pdf"],
  ["Item2song", "http://somewebsite.com/item2.mp3"],
  ["Item3zip", "http://somewebsite.com/item3.zip"]
?>
```

The goal is to send the buyer an email containing the link that corresponds to the `item_name` using the `$digital_product_path` variable.

The Email snippet Would look something like this:

```
if(strtoupper($payment_status) == 'COMPLETED')
{
    $mail -> Subject  =  'Download File Here';
    $mail -> Body = $digital_product_path;
    $mail -> AddAddress($payer_email, $first_name);
    $mail -> Send();
    $mail -> ClearAddresses();
}
```

I tried somthing like this but it does not acheive the desired effect (it just emails the URL corresponding to the last $digital_product_path):

```
if($item_name = 'Item1book')  
{
  $digital_product_path = 'http://somewebsite.com/item1.pdf';
}
if($item_name = 'Item2song')  
{
  $digital_product_path = 'http://somewebsite.com/item2.mp3';
}
```

How would one go about making this work?

Answer (score 2):

```
if($item_name = 'Item2song')
```

`=` is an assignment operator. You have to use `==` (equal) or `===` (identical), as such:

```
if($item_name == 'Item2song')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex M is right. or you use `switch`, which is the better choice for your problem imho:

```
switch($item_name)
{
    case 'Item1book':
        $digital_product_path = 'http://somewebsite.com/item1.pdf';
    break;
    case 'Item2song':
        $digital_product_path = 'http://somewebsite.com/item2.mp3';
    break;
    default: 
        //unknown item-string
    break;
}
```

Comment: Even better, `$data = [ 'item1book' => 'url..', 'item2song' => ... ]` ... `if (isset($data[$item_name]) { $digi... = $data[$item_name]; }`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help and insight!

Although there are always an infinite amount of possibilities, The working solution I found is:

```
if($item_name == 'item1book')
{
$digital_product_path = 'http://somewebsite.com/item1.pdf';
}
if ($item_name == 'item2song')
{
$digital_product_path = 'http://somewebsite.com/item2.mp3';
}
```

Comment: I would like to also note that where the PHP code is located is important, there is an order of operation where the codes location matters I have learned!

Comment: this is exactly what Alex M answered. you should accept his answer.